# In what order does the compiler search through the namespaces/binaries to find a variable name?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I was just curious how this worked. Can't seem to find much detail on it. Probably not wording the question right in my searches. But basically, how does the compiler resolve names? in what order does it search through the namespaces listed in the using statements at the beginning of a C# file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the order they are specified. Using directives are effectively "dumb", in the sense that the compiler attempts to prepend each namespace you've added with using over unqualified types. If no fully qualified type matches, you get a not found error. If more than one matches, you get an ambiguous type error.

From [CLR Via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454) 3rd edition (link is to the 4th edition):

> Using the C# using directive is entirely optional; you’re always welcome to type out the fully
>   qualified name of a type if you prefer. The C# using directive instructs the compiler to try
>   prepending different prefixes to a type name until a match is found.